# Why is intent.remove extra not working as you would think?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

I am trying to change the value of an intent extra. I associate the value alarmId with my intent by using intent.putextra("alarmId", id). I am trying to reassign the id value the line above where I assign the value so I can reuse the alarmId text key. I've tried intent.removeextra("alarmId"), but it does not seem to do anything. I'm away from computer atm, so I don't remember if it is exactly that method, remove extra. But the one the ide recognizes does not work. Neither does setting the extra bundle to null. using kotlin.

Comment: Can’t tell exactly what you’re doing, expecting, and getting from the loose description.

Comment: Am trying to pass an id in an intent as an extra. The problem I am having is I can not seem to replace the original value in the intent to reuse the same string key, but change the value tied to the key.

Comment: You’re trying to reuse an Intent instance? I can’t think of how that would make sense.

Answer (score 1):

This actually bad way for using intent. If you already set key-value you can't use same key in same activity. Based on your case, more better use SharedPreference [check it here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)